# Putting image on top of a canvas

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint, graphics2d

Currently I have a canvas which was been made using the `paint()` method. I have .png images of counters I want to move on the board. How would I create the `JPanel` to be able to do this? Which pane do I use to get the counter image on top of the board canvas?

Comment: Why not just paint the images directly onto the canvas, since you're performing custom painting anyway?

Comment: @MadProgrammer how would I go about doing this? Can't seem to find a clear example.

Comment: `Graphics#drawImage`, maybe start with [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29088318/java-add-image-to-canvas by @MadProgrammer :)